# How to change a video url with text form and submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, video, replace

I'm trying to make it so that my site has a textbox and a submit button on a form.  When a user enters the URL of a video in the textbox and clicks submit, JavaScript should replace a certain block of text with that URL.

Here's my code. I'm new to JavaScript and thanks for the help in advance!:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta type="utf-8">
<title> Vid_hack </title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
a:link { color: #CC0000 ; text-decoration: bold}
a:active { color: #CC0000 ; text-decoration: none}
a:visited { color: #CC0000; text-decoration: none}
a:hover { color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: bold; background: #336699}

body {

background-color: #222222;

}
</style>
<body>
<div align="center">
<p center="" style="background: #444444; border-radius: 15px; border: solid 3.0pt white; padding: 10px">


<object><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"></param><p id="url"><embed src="INSERT-VIDEO-URL-HERE" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="1" width="800" height="600"></embed></p></object>

<BR>
<BR>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="vid" value="Insert URL here" maxlength="200" />
<br>
<button onclick="return vid()">Play</button>
</form>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
function vid()
{
var txt = $("#vid").attr("value");
$("#url embed").attr("src",txt);
return false;
}
</script>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
<span style="color: #FFF" align="center">
<BR>
<BR>
Please view the included README file for more information.
</span>
</p>
</div>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want do that:

```
<script>
var flash_wrapper = 
'<object><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"></param><p id="url"><embed src="INSERT-VIDEO-URL-HERE" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="1" width="800" height="600"></embed></p></object>'

document.write(flash_wrapper)
</script>

</script>
<BR>
<BR>
<form method="post" name="myForm" onsubmit="return valid()">
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="Insert URL here" maxlength="100" />
<br>
<button>Play</button>
</form>

<script>
function valid(){
    var url = document.myForm.first_name.value;
    var str = document.getElementById("url").innerHTML; 
    var n = str.replace("INSERT-VIDEO-URL-HERE", url);
    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = n;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Prefer place onsubmit on the form, because if the user press enter and so don't click on the button, he bypasses the validation. And i complete your code for replace url in html et add return false at the end of the function for prevent submit of form else it reload page.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in its current form you will only get to change the video URL once since on the second button click the innerHTML will no longer contain INSERT-VIDEO-URL-HERE but instead contain the URL from the first button click. That may or may not be desired.

Assuming that's not an unexpected behavior then you just need to change the innerHTML with `n` after you've replaced it with the url from the form field. See below

```
function vid()
{
    var str=document.getElementById("url").innerHTML; 
    var n=str.replace("INSERT-VIDEO-URL-HERE", document.forms[0].elements[0].value);
    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML = n;
}
```

Note that this is just a quick solve that makes a couple assumptions without knowing the surrounding HTML. There are a few things that could improve the code overall:

1. Avoid document.write. At the minimum, add the flash to a wrapper and do something like `document.getElementsById('#flash_wrapper').innerHTML = flash_wrapper;`
2. Avoid inline javascript events (like using the onclick attribute). http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

If you plan on writing more javascript in the future that interacts with the page contents, I'd suggest learning jQuery at http://jquery.com as it takes a lot of headaches out of the picture and is pretty straightforward to learn.

Answer (score 0):

this relies on jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
var flash_wrapper = 
'<object><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"></param><p id="url"><embed  src="INSERT-VIDEO-URL-HERE" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="1" width="800" height="600"></embed></p></object>'

document.write(flash_wrapper)
</script>
<BR>
<BR>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="first_name" value="Insert URL here" maxlength="100" />
<br>
<button onclick="return vid()">Play</button>
</form>

<script>
function vid()
{ 
    var txt = $("#first_name").attr("value");
    $("#url embed").attr("src",txt);
    return false; 
}
</script>​
```

try it out
http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/jDhNc/